# asp-action returns wrong value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm trying to edit a record with a form by POST method.

//Record.cshtml

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Edit">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Asp-action returns url adress record/edit/id but should return just record/edit because I specified post method. 
Why is this happening?

RecordController

```
        [Route("edit/{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
             //get record from database
             return View(recordViewModel)
        }

        [Route("edit")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(RecordViewModel record)
        {
             //edit record 
        }
```

//Startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Auth}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
```

Comment: Is your Edit method for post getting executed?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem could be changing the name of Edit post method.